# Using Yahoo in my iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, yahoo-search

I'm using Yahoo search facility in my app (not YQL or API's) but i'm wondering if i submit the app for review is it going to come up against any copyright violations??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly how, if you don't use the API, are you using Yahoo's search? Are you posting the raw http to Yahoo?

You have to read the terms of service of Yahoo to see if this is an issue:

> 12 . NO COMMERCIAL REUSE OF YAHOO! SERVICES
>
> You agree not to reproduce, duplicate,
>   copy, sell, trade, resell or exploit
>   for any commercial purposes, any
>   portion or use of, or access to, the
>   Yahoo! Services (including Content,
>   advertisements, Software and your
>   Yahoo! ID).

And why not use the API? Using Yahoo's API is no more a violation of the iOS development license than Twitteriffic using the Twitter API.

My feeling is even if everything is up and up with Yahoo, you'll probably get pinged on this when your app gets reviewed because it looks like you're doing something sneaky. Better off using the API.